# should this spread object in JSX show properties after transpiling?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jsx, spread

I have this code

```
const d = {
  c: 3
};

<Mycomponent {...d} >
  hi
</ Mycomponent>
```

in babel this is converted to

```
var d = {
  c: 3
};

/*#__PURE__*/
React.createElement(Mycomponent, d, "hi");
```

Why is the 'd' value not expanded into it's property such as this:

```
{c: 3}
```

I ask, because when I do

```
<Mycomponent d={4} >
  hi
</ Mycomponent>
```

it shows as

```
/*#__PURE__*/
React.createElement(Mycomponent, {
  d: 4
}, "hi");
```

Comment: "*this is what I expected to happen*" - but you **do** get the `{c: 3}` object passed to `Mycomponent`? Can you post the complete transpiler output that you expected, please?

Comment: @Bergi I guess I expected the output of the first transpiled version to look like the second one, where instead of a simple reference to the 'd' object, it would explicitly list it's keys and values, as it seems this is what the spread operator should return.

Comment: `<Component {...obj} x={1}>` is equivalent to `createElement(Component, {...obj, x:1})` in general. If you omit any extra properties, it becomes `createElement(Component, {...obj})` which is optimised into `createElement(Component, obj)` as there's no point in cloning the object if props are immutable anyway.

Comment: To clarify, when you say optimised and cloning, you mean if there are no extra properties then it just references the original object? secondly, the thing I still don't get is why does it just show the object name in the first version but in the second transpiled version it lists the key and value in the `createElement` call, is it because in the second case it doesn't have a name reference it can use so it has to list the object explicitly?

Comment: Yes, the object spread syntax is only necessary when there are extra properties. I'm not certain I understand your second question. An attribute in jsx becomes a property in the passed object. If you're not using jsx spread syntax, your `d` variable isn't used at all.

Comment: *An attribute in jsx becomes a property in the passed object.* When I use `a={1}` in the jsx element, the transpiled version shows the explicit property and value `{d: 4}`. However when I use `{...d}` then it just references the `d` object in the transpiled code. From your answers I understand it shows the `d` object name as an optimisation in the transpiled version. My expectation was it would show `{c : 3}` instead of `d`. If I understood correctly this is due to an optimisation which stops it displaying explicitly the keys and values. Please let me know if right

Comment: No. JSX simply has no idea what the value of `d` is. It's a js variable, and its value might be dynamically constructed. That you initialised `const d = {c: 3}` is not known to the jsx syntax transpiler.

Comment: @Bergi ok but JSX knows that its an object if I am spreading it in the JSX element? and in the transpiled version if it references `d` as the 2nd argument of `createElement` then it must also know it's an object as that's what goes into 2nd argument, is that right so far? Even if the value was dynamically constructed, I expected that once its' passed into `createElement` the function would know what it's received and spread the object if that's how you pass it in - on that point though, I think the optimisation is stopping it needing to be spread. Is that right?

Comment: I think you're confusing compile-time behaviour with runtime behaviour here

Comment: Ok, sorry I am confused.Just to understand the part why `d` is transpiled into `createElement` with `d` then and not `{c: 3}` - this is because JSX doesn't know what `d` is even though it should expect an object? can you just summarise an answer for that bit please as I've got lost with the comments.

Comment: @Bergi I've just been through all the comments a few times and I'm lost, hope you can clarify please, would appreciate it. thanks